# Change to transparent rectangle

Tags: c++, windows, graphics

I'm using this code :

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "gdi32.lib" )

int main()
{
    HDC dc = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
    while (1) {

        SetDCBrushColor(dc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        SelectObject(dc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
        Rectangle(dc, 200, 200, 400, 400);

        SetDCBrushColor(dc,TRANSPARENT));
        SelectObject(dc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
        Rectangle(dc, 200, 200, 400, 400);

        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

As you can see it prints red screen and than change to TRANSPARENT but beside change to transparent it changes to black screen.
My goal is to show the red rectangle and than as quick as possible delete it. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `TRANSPARENT` means don't paint it. Maybe you want white?

Comment: nope I want it to be in the colors of the window under the square. For example, if the square above the Facebook logo I want to see the Facebook logo.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using the desktop window and drawing on it. You should create a top-most transparent window of your own and paint into that.